# jQuery append, when I delete record view has changed baldy

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I list some values using `append`

```
 <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">

        <h2 id="list-filter">Lista produktów z lodówki</h2>
        <div data-demo-html="true">
            <ul data-role="listview" id="produktList" data-filter="true" data-filter-placeholder="Search fruits..." data-inset="true">

            </ul>

            <div id="deleteButton"><input type="button" id="merge_button" value="Usuń"></div>
        </div><!--/demo-html -->

    </div>
```

And JS

```
 function iterateOverLocalStorage() {
            $('ul#produktList').html("");
            for(var i=0; i < localStorage.length; i++)
            {
                console.log(localStorage.getItem(localStorage.key(i)));
                $('ul#produktList').append("<li class='ui-li-static ui-body-inherit ui-first-child ui-last-child'>"+localStorage.getItem(localStorage.key(i))+"" +
                        "<span><input type='checkbox' id='check' name='produkty[]' value='"+i+"'></span></li>");
            }



        }
        iterateOverLocalStorage();
```

It looks ok

[image]

When I click `Usuń` button and this action was deleted selected record

```
  $("#merge_button").click(function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
            var searchIDs = $("input:checkbox:checked").map(function(){

                return this.value;

            }).toArray(); // <----
            console.log(searchIDs);

            if(searchIDs.length == 0)
            {
                alert('Nic nie zaznaczyles');
            }else {

                for (var k in searchIDs) {
                    console.log("Element: " + k);


                    localStorage.removeItem(localStorage.key(k));
                }

                alert("Usunalem");
                iterateOverLocalStorage();
            }

        });
```

The view changes, why?

[image]

Comment: What exactly does "The view changes" refer to? It of course should have changed, you told it to.

Comment: @KevinB take look on images

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two views are different because the radio buttons in the first view were created on document load, while the radio buttons in the second view were created at a later stage.

jQuery Mobile enhances the document at page load, right after you insert the initial set of radio buttons. But this enhancement does not happen automatically when you inject HTML at a later stage; instead you must request jQuery Mobile to apply the enhancement, for example with the [`enhanceWithin` method](https://api.jquerymobile.com/enhancewithin/).

For that to happen, change this:

```
$('ul#produktList').append(
    "<li class='ui-li-static ui-body-inherit ui-first-child ui-last-child'>"
    +localStorage.getItem(localStorage.key(i))+"" +
    "<span><input type='checkbox' id='check' name='produkty[]' value='"
    +i+"'></span></li>");
```

to:

```
$("<li class='ui-li-static ui-body-inherit ui-first-child ui-last-child'>"
    +localStorage.getItem(localStorage.key(i)) +
    "<span><input type='checkbox' id='check' name='produkty[]' value='"
    +i+"'></span></li>").appendTo('ul#produktList').enhanceWithin();
```

Also, although not really necessary, I would advise to add the initial radio buttons in the same conditions as in the click scenario, adding them *after* the initial enhancement phase. This way they are added in a consistent manner, relying on the enhancement that is triggered with the above code in both cases.

This you can do as follows. Replace this line (the one which occurs outside any function):

```
iterateOverLocalStorage();
```

with this:

```
$(document).on("pagecreate",function(){
    iterateOverLocalStorage();
});
```

---

Note that there are several events that get triggered when jQuery Mobile pages load or transition. Check out this image:

[image]

Comment: Not correct. He has to enhance added elements manually `.checkboxradio()` or `.enhanceWithin()`.

Comment: @Omar, thank you for pointing that out: you are right. I have updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: @trincot it works but when I add this. My listview is not with jquery mobile styles. Help